# Create generator that yields coroutine results as the coroutines finish

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

Currently, I have an inefficient synchronous generator that makes many HTTP requests in sequence and yields the results. I'd like to use [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and [`aiohttp`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to parallelise the requests and thereby speed up this generator, but I want to keep it as an ordinary generator (not a [PEP 525 async generator](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep525)) so that the non-async code that calls it doesn't need to be modified. How can I create such a generator?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`asyncio.as_completed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) takes an iterable of coroutines or futures and returns an iterable of futures in the order that the input futures complete. *Normally*, you'd loop over its result and `await` the members from inside an `async` function...

```
import asyncio

async def first():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    return 'first'

async def second():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 'second'

async def third():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return 'third'

async def main():
    for future in asyncio.as_completed([first(), second(), third()]):
        print(await future)

# Prints 'second', then 'third', then 'first'
asyncio.run(main())
```

... but for the purpose of this question, what we want is to be able to yield these results from an ordinary generator, so that normal synchronous code can consume them without ever knowing that `async` functions are being used under the hood. We can do that by calling `loop.run_until_complete()` on the futures yielded by our `as_completed` call...

```
import asyncio

async def first():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    return 'first'

async def second():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 'second'

async def third():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return 'third'

def ordinary_generator():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for future in asyncio.as_completed([first(), second(), third()]):
        yield loop.run_until_complete(future)

# Prints 'second', then 'third', then 'first'
for element in ordinary_generator():
    print(element)
```

In this way, we've exposed our async code to non-async-land in a manner that doesn't require callers to define any functions as `async`, or to even know that `ordinary_generator` is using `asyncio` under the hood.

As an alternative implementation of `ordinary_generator()` that offers more flexibility in some circumstances, we can repeatedly call [`asyncio.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) with the `FIRST_COMPLETED` flag instead of looping over `as_completed()`:

```
import concurrent.futures

def ordinary_generator():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    pending = [first(), second(), third()]
    while pending:
        done, pending = loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.wait(
                pending,
                return_when=concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED
            )
        )
        for job in done:
            yield job.result()
```

This approach, maintaining a list of `pending` jobs, has the advantage that we can adapt it to add jobs to the `pending` list on the fly. This is useful in use cases where our async jobs can add an unpredictable number of further jobs to the queue - like a web spider that follows all links on each page that it visits.

One caveat: the approaches above assume we're calling the synchronous code from the main thread, in which case `get_event_loop` is guaranteed to give us a loop and we've got no need to `.close` it. If we want `ordinary_generator` to be usable from a non-main thread, especially one that may have previously had an event loop created, then life gets harder, because we can't rely on `get_event_loop` (it raises a `RuntimeError` on any non-main thread that doesn't have an event loop yet). In that case the simplest thing I can think to do is to spin off a *new* thread to run our `asyncio` code, and communicate with it via a queue:

```
def ordinary_generator():
    sentinel = object()
    queue = Queue()

    def thread_entry_point():
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        for future in asyncio.as_completed([first(), second(), third()]):
            try:
                queue.put(loop.run_until_complete(future))
            except Exception as e:
                queue.put((sentinel, e))
                break
        loop.close()
        queue.put(sentinel)

    Thread(target=thread_entry_point).start()
    while True:
        val = queue.get()
        if val is sentinel:
            return
        if isinstance(val, tuple) and len(val) == 2 and val[0] is sentinel:
            raise val[1]
        yield val
```

(Combining the use of `run_until_complete` from the penultimate example with the use of an extra thread in the final example is left as an exercise for any reader who needs to do so.)

Answer (score 1):

Mark's answer is great but I'd like to contribute a different implementation that doesn't rely on the low level event loop methods.

The key difference is that rather than doing a `yield`, instead provide a callback that can be used to process the results:

```py
import asyncio
import random

async def do_stuff():
    proc_time = round(random.random(), 2)
    print('START: ', proc_time)
    await asyncio.sleep(proc_time)
    return proc_time


def concurrent_stuff(awaitables, callback):
    # Must be async to wait
    async def _as_completed():
        for coro in asyncio.as_completed(awaitables):
            result = await coro
            callback(result)  # Send result to callback.

    # Perform the async calls inside a regular method
    asyncio.run(_as_completed())


def when_done(result):
    print('FINISHED: ', result)


def main():
    awaitables = [do_stuff() for _ in range(5)]
    concurrent_stuff(awaitables, when_done)


main()

# START:  0.56
# START:  0.98
# START:  0.39
# START:  0.23
# START:  0.94
# FINISHED:  0.23
# FINISHED:  0.39
# FINISHED:  0.56
# FINISHED:  0.94
# FINISHED:  0.98
```