# Can't run asyncio.wait(...) on a list of futures

Tags: python-3.6, python-asyncio

I'm submitting coroutines to an event loop in a separate thread. This all works well when I wait on each future in sequence with `future.next()`. But I want to now wait on the first completed future in a list of futures. I'm trying to use `asyncio.wait(...)` for that, but I appear to be using it incorrectly.

Below is a simplified example. I'm getting the exception `TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required` at the line `done, pending = future.result()`.

This works if I pass `[c1, c2, c3]` to `asyncio.wait([c1, c2, c3], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETE)`, but I am submitting tasks at random times, so I only can gather the set of futures, not the original tasks. And the documentation clearly states that you can use futures.

> `coroutine asyncio.wait(futures, *, loop=None, timeout=None, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)`
>
> Wait for the Futures and coroutine objects given by the sequence futures to complete. Coroutines will be wrapped in Tasks. Returns two sets of Future: (done, pending).

```
import asyncio
import threading


async def generate():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    return 'Hello'


def run_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()


event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
threading.Thread(target=lambda: run_loop(event_loop)).start()

c1 = generate()  # submitted at a random time
c2 = generate()  # submitted at a random time
c3 = generate()  # submitted at a random time
f1 = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(c1, event_loop)
f2 = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(c2, event_loop)
f3 = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(c3, event_loop)

all_futures = [f1, f2, f3]

# I'm doing something wrong in these 3 lines
waitable = asyncio.wait(all_futures, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(waitable, event_loop)
done, pending = future.result()  # This returns my TypeError exception

for d in done:
    print(d.result())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asyncio.wait` expects **asyncio** futures and works inside an event loop. To wait for multiple `concurrent.futures` futures (and outside of an event loop), use [`concurrent.futures.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait) instead:

```
done, pending = concurrent.futures.wait(
    all_futures, return_when=concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

Note that your idea would have worked if you had access to the underlying asyncio futures. For example (untested):

```
async def submit(coro):
    # submit the coroutine and return the asyncio task (future)
    return asyncio.create_task(coro)

# ...generate() as before

# note that we use result() to get to the asyncio futures:
f1 = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(submit(c1), event_loop).result()
f2 = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(submit(c2), event_loop).result()
f3 = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(submit(c3), event_loop).result()

# these should be waitable by submitting wait() to the event loop
done, pending = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
    asyncio.wait([f1, f2, f3], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)).result()
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer was instrumental in helping answer this:

[Create generator that yields coroutine results as the coroutines finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901795/create-generator-that-yields-coroutine-results-as-the-coroutines-finish)

`asyncio.wait(...)` can't take futures, only coroutines and awaitables that have NOT yet been scheduled. The correct way to do this is with a callback. When the future finishes it can just add itself to a thread safe queue and you can pull from that queue. The example below fixes the problem in the question:

```
import asyncio
import threading
import queue
import random


async def generate(i):
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(5, 10))
    return 'Hello {}'.format(i)


def run_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()


def done(fut):
    q.put(fut)


event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
threading.Thread(target=lambda: run_loop(event_loop)).start()
q = queue.Queue()

c1 = generate(1)
c2 = generate(2)
c3 = generate(3)
f1 = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(c1, event_loop)
f2 = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(c2, event_loop)
f3 = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(c3, event_loop)
f1.add_done_callback(lambda fut: q.put(fut))
f2.add_done_callback(lambda fut: q.put(fut))
f3.add_done_callback(lambda fut: q.put(fut))

print(q.get().result())
print(q.get().result())
print(q.get().result())
```