# Requests and generator. Parallel Compute and request

Tags: python, python-requests

I am **scraping** blog urls from main page, and later I iterate over all urls to retrive text on it.
Will generator be faster if I move loop to `blogscraper` and make `yield some_text` ? I guess app will still be one threaded and It wont request next pages while computing text from html.

Should I use asyncio? or there are some better modules to make it parrel?  [Create generator that yields coroutine results as the coroutines finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901795/create-generator-that-yields-coroutine-results-as-the-coroutines-finish)

I also want to make later small rest app for displaying results

```
def readmainpage(self):
   blogurls = []
   while(nextPage):       
       r = requests.get(url)
       ...
       blogurls += [new_url]
   return blogurls


def blogscraper(self, url):
   r = request.get(url)
   ...
   return sometext

def run(self):
    blog_list = self.readmainpage()
    for blog in blog_list:
        data = self.blogscraper(blog['url'])
```

Comment: In order to make it really fast you could try to use [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) which was built for just that, fast web-scraping...

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ and __scraper__ not scrapping or scrapper

Answer (score 0):

Using threading package, you can run your top function (object initialitization) asynchronously. It will create sub parallel sub-process for your requests. For example, single page fetching is 2 mins and you have 10 pages. In threading, all will take 2 mins. [Threading in Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Answer (score 0):

With asyncio you can try to use aiohttp [module](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html):
`pip install aiohttp`
As example code it's can looks something like this, also can be done some improvements but it depends on your code...

```py
import sys
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import socket
from urllib.parse import urlparse

class YourClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "..."
        url_parsed = urlparse( self.url )
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(
            headers = { "Referer": f"{ url_parsed.scheme }://{ url_parsed.netloc }" },
            auto_decompress = True,
            connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(family=socket.AF_INET, verify_ssl=False) )


    async def featch(self, url):
        async with self.session.get( url ) as resp:
            assert resp.status == 200
            return await resp.text()

    async def readmainpage(self):
        blogurls = []
        while nextPage:       
            r = await self.featch(self.url)
            # ...
            blogurls += [new_url]
        return blogurls


    async def blogscraper(self, url):
        r = await self.featch(url)
        return r
        # ...
        return sometext

    async def __call__(self):
        url_parsed = urlparse( self.url )
        blog_list = await self.readmainpage()
        coros = [ asyncio.Task( self.blogscraper( blog['url']) ) for blog in blog_list ]
        
        for data in await asyncio.gather( *coros ):
            print(data)

        # do not forget to close session if not using with statement
        await self.session.close()
        

def main():
    featcher = YourClass()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete( featcher() )
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```